# C++ fopen error on windows server 2008

Tags: c++, fopen, fgets

I try to open file "job.ini" using function fopen is this way:
    iniFile = fopen("job.ini", "r");

debugging, the file is opened and then i try to read data from file using:
    fgets(buffer, STR_SIZE, iniFile);

when i run (in debug mode) this program in pc having windows server 2003 (32 bit) this work perfectly.
When i try to run on windows server 2008 R2 (64 bit) the iniFile read seems to be incorrect.
The loop reading file:

```
  do{
    fgets(buffer, STR_SIZE, iniFile);
    if(strncmp(buffer, section, strlen(section)) == 0) return TRUE;
  }while(!feof(iniFile));
```

is infinite...

anyone have idea why this work on windows server 2003 (32 bit) and not on windows server 2008 (64 bit)?

Extract of job.ini file:

```
[job]
ErrorPath = e:\@\bcne\batch\bin\
Database = MYDATABASE
Userid = myuser
Password = mypassword
LanguageId = 2
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason *might* be that the end-of-file flag isn't set until *after* `fgets` fails, which means that you will call `strcncmp` with an undefined buffer contents.

I recommend you to change the loop to this:

```
while (fgets(buffer, STR_SIZE, iniFile))
{
    if (strncmp(buffer, section, strlen(section)) == 0)
        return TRUE;
}
```

Also remember that `fgets` keeps the newlines it reads in the buffer, which means that `section` also must contain a newline for the `strncmp` to match the strings.

Comment: thank you for your answer. now i will try. I've also noticed that buffer, after fgets on windows server 2003 (32 bit) is correctly set with "[job]" (the first entry present on file job.ini) but in windows server 2008 (64 bit) buffer is always not initialized (has before fgets)...